# Current date, current month?

Tags: crystal-reports

Iam trying to display a create date unless the create date is in the current month - then I would like to say "New Record" but someting is wrong with my formula as I am getting an error saying "a date is required here" but I just want the system to validate whether the create date is in the current month - I don't want to modify this report every 1st day of the month - is that possible? Thanks in advance for your help.

if ({SyndMail_Errors.Create Date} =  Month(currentdate())) then "New Record"
else {SyndMail_Errors.Create Date}

Comment: Do you need to check the year as well as the month?  In other words, do you have create dates from a year ago or more?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DateVar FirstDate := Date(year(CurrentDateTime), month(CurrentDateTime), 1);
if ({SyndMail_Errors.Create Date} >= FirstDate) then "New Record" else
    ToText({SyndMail_Errors.Create Date},"MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: Thank you the first portion works perfect but I get an error for the ELSE part of the statement - it is looking for a string.

Comment: @Calypso:  Ok.  Converted date to text in answer.